# Get rid of radeon.modeset=0

Tags: drivers, 16.04, graphics, radeon

I have a *MSI GX70* notebook with two video cards: integrated *Radeon HD 8650G* and discrete *Radeon HD 8970G*. Up to and including Ubuntu 15.10, I used `fglrx`. Then came Ubuntu 16.04, where `fglrx` no longer works; and neither does it in 14.04.5 with the new version of X.org.

`amdgpu` and `amdgpu-pro` are no options as they don't support *Radeon HD 8650G*.

Which leaves us `radeon`. However, hardware acceleration (and therefore games), second monitor connection, power managament, switching to integrated card from discrete do not work, since I have `radeon.modeset=0` in my `/etc/default/grub`.

I cannot remove this line from kernel options, because in this case the system won't boot at all. It will switch several times from one video card to another, then reboot, and so on.

So, effectively there are no drivers for those cards under the current Ubuntu version, and the LTS is broken, too.

Is there any escape from downgrading (i.e. re-installing the OS) to a non-LTS old version of Ubuntu?